# Derivatives with log base e

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

So I am currently finding the derivative of logs and can perform most of them out. But the question states,
$$
\log_e{\sqrt{2x+1}}
$$
How do you derive this?

Comment: Hint: you'll need the chain rule.

Comment: No, he does not.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos how come? Even if the chain rule is embedded in the usual derivation rule for the logarithm, it does not mean it is not being used.

Comment: I just mean that the OP doesn't *need* to use the chain rule directly (with $g(x)=\log x$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+1}$, since $\log\left(\sqrt{2x+1}\right)=\frac12\log(2x+1)=\frac12\left(\log(2)+\log\left(x+\frac12\right)\right)$. One may say that the chain rule is still needed to differentiate $\log\left(x+\frac12\right)$, but that's a bit forced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$y=\log_e (f(x)^n)=n\ln(f(x))$$
$$y'=n\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
your $f(x)=2x+1$ and $n=\frac{1}{2}$